# CMake flag changes debug configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a project running on CMake 2.8.9, and use Visual Studio 2008 for building. In the CMakeLists.txt I switch the default runtime library for debug configuration to MTd:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd")
```

Unfortunately, this line also causes switching the flag "Debug Information Format" to "Disabled", which means that I can't debug my project. :-(

If I remove the line from the CMakeLists.txt the runtime library is "MDd" and also the "Debug Information Format" is "Program Database (/Zi)". Does anybody know the reason or how to avoid the issue? Is there any workaround? Is it possible to set the missing flag via CMake?

Comment: Perhaps it's because another flag is removed when you set this? What does `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` contain before you set it? You can show it with `message("Flag: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely only want to *add* that flag to the list of used flags instead of *replacing* the list of flags with the single token `/MTd`.

To append `/MTd` to the list of flags use

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
```